# How much freedom is there in a quantum field?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, foundations

Let's imagine we have a free scalar quantum field, and that it has 2 particles in a specific momentum eigenstate only. Does this information completely fix the quantum field, or is there additional information needed, like correlations / entanglements between the particles or something?

There could be some additional subtlety to this question and I can imagine more than 2 possible answers, for example:

- There is just one mathematical state that corresponds to a field with 2 particles in a specific momentum eigenstate only.
- There are multiple formal states that correspond to this but they have identical phenomenology / the freedom is in the model only.
- There are multiple states that have this interpretation and they exhibit different phenomenology.

Edit:

To be a bit clearer about the motivation for my question: if I were to talk about a Fock space in a state containing 2 particles at 2 positions, this is not enough to uniquely specify the state. It could mean equal chance of both particles at each point, or certainty of a single particle at each point (ie. 
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} a_{x1}^\dagger a_{x1}^\dagger |0\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} a_{x2}^\dagger a_{x2}^\dagger |0\rangle$ or $a_{x1}^\dagger a_{x2}^\dagger |0\rangle$ I believe) This sort of idea is what I was thinking of when I wrote "correlations / entanglements". I'm not necessarily referring to any specific meaning of "correlations" or "entanglements".

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking - a quantum field is an *operator*, not a state, but your entire question sounds as if you think the quantum field should somehow be part of the state information.

Comment: Thank you, could you please help me with the terminology? What should I call the domain/set of states upon which the operator acts, ie. the "stuff" that the universe (or in this case toy universe) is made of?

Comment: ACM is correct but being a bit strict. The object we call a quantum field is indeed an operator field, a mathematical object, but it is describing a real object i.e. the free scalar field. The eigenstates of this object are called Fock states. The Fock states cannot become entangled since in a free field there are no interactions to entangle them. The overall state of the field is a product of the Fock states.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Regarding the terminology, I would love to know the precise answer so I can be clearer in my questions, but instead of clearing it up here I have moved to a whole question so any answer can have proper status: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/420015/what-is-the-state-space-of-a-quantum-field-called

Comment: @John Rennie please don't get hung up on my usage of the word "entangled", this is the kind of thing I don't yet understand properly and just a kind of indication in a general direction. What I mean is for a Fock state of two particles at two positions, it could either be 50% chance of 2 particles at either position, or 100% chance of particles at both positions. So there is some additional correlation information required.

Comment: Your edit sounds to answer the question. Those are two different states with different physical observable.

Comment: @ShanePKelly In my edit I talk about two different position values, but the question itself asks about two particles with only a single momentum value, so I think the question and edit are different subjects even if the answer is the same?

Comment: I see, I was think two particles in two different modes.  Two particles in one mode completely specifies the state

Comment: @ShanePKelly ok thank you! If you post this as an answer I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state of a quantum field is fully described by a state in Fock-Space.

Thus in general the number of particles in a given set of modes is not enough information as you gave in you example of:

$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} a_{x1}^\dagger a_{x1}^\dagger |0\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} a_{x2}^\dagger a_{x2}^\dagger |0\rangle
\neq
a_{x1}^\dagger a_{x2}^\dagger |0\rangle
$

In otherwords, the state of your field is not described by just the single particle correlations $\left<a_{x2}^\dagger a_{x1}\right>$.  You need to specify all n particle correlations to give a full description of the state.  If your state has $N$ particles in it then all correlations up to the $N$ particle correlation function will be enough.

If your state only has **exactly** n particles in one mode, then you  have specified all the information.  There is only one state of this situation:

$
(a^{\dagger})^n|0\rangle
$

but you could have a coherent state where on average you have $n$ particles in one mode, but the number particles is not fixed:
$e^{\alpha a^\dagger-\alpha^* a}\left|0\right> $ with $\left<a^\dagger a\right>=\alpha^2$

Comment: Thank you so much, very helpful answer. Good to know there is no extra 'magic', and the extra info was spot on. For anybody else reading "correlation function" is apparently a standard term and you can read more at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_function_(quantum_field_theory) .