# What are “vibrations” in a field in Quantum Field Theory (QFT)?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, vibrations, popular-science

For example, in a 2013 article for NOVA Don Lincoln writes:

> Everywhere in the universe there is a field called the electron field. A physical electron isn’t the field, but rather a localized vibration in the field. In fact, every electron in the universe is a similar localized vibration of that single field.

https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/article/the-good-vibrations-of-quantum-field-theories/

He doesn’t really talk about where he came up with the word “vibration,” but uses it as if it’s a normal term. Is this a pop-sci metaphor, or is this a real thing? What solid intro to QFT can I read for a reliable translation of the science to a college grad who took two semesters of physics (basic Newtonian physics, and electromagnetism) ages ago?

Will such an intro likely use the word “vibration” and explain why we use that instead of “particle,” or is “vibration” a terrible approximation for the real concept, and a reliable intro would never use that term?

Comment: You are right the term "vibration" as used here is a self-declared folksy synonym for the [technical "normal mode"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_quantization#Real_scalar_field) or ["phonon"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonon).  You may, or may not, be invited to think of a specific note on a string and analogize its mathematics to that of quantum field theory, but your remonstrance obviates the pedagogical tack attempted.

Comment: *"A physical electron isn’t the field, but rather a localized vibration in the field."* - this type of description has perplexed me for some time.  In QFT, there are the operator fields (operators indexed by their coordinates in spacetime) that create and destroy quanta.  But a single electron state with definite momentum isn't a 'vibration' in this operator field is it?  In other words, what precisely is the entity with states in the Fock space?

Comment: @Afred Centauri A single electron state of momentum *p* is the normal mode of that field with momentum index *p*, in its first excited state. We prefer to work in Fourier space because that's where the normal modes decouple, and the Fock space description is practical, but not ineluctable. Spacetime localization in QFT is always approximate and, basically, flakey.

Comment: You would need some Quantum Mechanics to really get going but this is the most accessible and yet not "populist" resource I can think of: http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html

Comment: @CosmasZachos, I understand that the definite momentum state $p$ is the normal mode with momentum index $p$ - that's not the question I posed.  As I understand it, there is at least (1) an operator valued field and (2) *something else* with states $|0\rangle, |...,1,...\rangle$, etc., correct?  When 'we' say that a particle is an excitation of 'the quantum field', what is it precisely that is excited?

Comment: The field. Excitation indicates first eigenstate above ground such, laddered by creation operator.

Comment: @CosmasZachos, to be clear, what is *"the field"*?

Comment: The quantum field in question pervading all space?

Comment: @CosmasZachos, I'm sorry I haven't made it clear that I'm asking what *"quantum field"* is excited from the ground state by a creation operator.  It isn't the operator field is it?  Maybe [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/420017/9887) by ACM will help (cont.)

Comment: *"Just like the classical observables of position and momentum get promoted to operators in quantum mechanics that act on such a space of states, quantum field theory promotes the classical fields of a field theory (e.g. electromagnetism) to **operators acting on a space of states**. The field is not the state, just like the position operator is not the state."*  (emphasis mine).

Comment: So, for the 1D QHO, there is the state space of the system and there are, among other things, the ladder operators $a^\dagger,\,a$.  The ladder operators *act* on states but do not *have* states (as far as I know).  When we say the QHO is in the one quanta (excitation) state $|1\rangle$, there is *something* with that state but (again, as far as I know), it is not the ladder operators we're referring to.

Comment: You might as well ask a self-standing question--hard to address here.  The state is $a_p^\dagger|0\rangle$, one out of the infinity of ingeniously repackaged (zilch displacement) ***abstract*** oscillators acting in Fock space.

Answer (score 1):

The word vibration has more of a historical sense, and we use excitation more often. In QFT, real particles are excitation of the underlying field.

Now the reason why we use vibration is because historically, these fields were modeled through waves, mathematically, and if you imagine a guitar string, and create a vibration, that will create a sound, a real thing, and so historically we use the expression vibration because it is very similar to a water surface where if it gets disturbed (excitation), it will create a wave, and these waves are modeling real particles in our currently accepted theories, the SM, GR, and QM, together with QFT.

Comment: Not in GR though. GR isn’t a QFT. Please edit

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus GR, at energies well below the Planck scale, is very much like any other standard effective field theory.

Comment: @Avantgarde that is a very tricky statement. GR is not an effective theory in Minkowski space. The Poincare group doesn’t act on GR states (it is a symmetry of one solution of GR, not the full theory). If you disagree, you’re welcome to tell me what the result of boosting the FLRW metric is.

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus I'm not sure how to answer that. GR as an EFT, however, has been in (active) study since the mid 90s, eg. https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9405057. There are many recent papers too.

Comment: That’s the perturbative expansion around the flat Minkowski space. I completely agree that it’s a QFT. However, the original formulation of GR by Einstein predicts objects that can never be understood perturbatively (black holes, cosmological expansion, etc — note that these objects live far from the Planck scale), so the perturbative version is not the full story.

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus Sure, perturbative version is not the full story. But that's true for the Standard Model too, or any theory for that matter. GR is not unique in that respect. Black holes today, in the era of gravitational wave astronomy, are intensively studied using standard black hole perturbation theory. Cosmological perturbation theory in FLRW spacetimes is also pretty standard. Of course, we all know it's not the full story, but at *relevant* length scales, as an *EFT*, it works pretty well.

Comment: @Avantgarde there’s a very clear distinction between Yang-Mills and GR. Classically, YM is formulated on flat spacetime, while GR is background independent. Perturbing around the vacuum (for YM) and around Minkowski geometry (for GR) we get two perturbative approximations that live on Minkowski background. Then we go quantum with these approximations which is doable for both (assuming you don’t care about near-Planck phenomena, ie rebornalizability). So now we seek a no perturbative completion of quantum theories, and here there’s a key difference.

Comment: @Avantgarde for YM, we expect the Minkowski structure to be intact, by definition (unless it is coupled to GR which we assume it’s not). This goes directly into Wightman axioms — it is the vanishing of the commutator for spacelike separated points (assume that we succeeded in defining Wightman YM QFT for the sake of the argument). That spacelike separation is a background structure given by the flat metric. In GR, you don’t expect the same to hold, as the light cone structure depends on the quantum metric $g=\eta+h$, not on $\eta$. This is the famous argument against perturbative gravity.